# Liberar memoria AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo un script de ajax que cada 5 segundos hace una consulta para actualizar un campo timestamp en una base de datos para un usuario concreto. Algo así como que cada 5 segundos dice... "eh, que estoy aquí". Esto funciona correctamente salvo por un punto:

La memoria no se está liberando y cuando pasas demasiado tiempo en una página, esta se empieza a sobrecargar y a veces incluso se cuelga. Cuanto más tiempo pasas en la página, peor.

He leído que existen 3 métodos para solucionarlo:

- Asegurarse de destruir el XMLHttpRequest una vez que ya no lo necesitas
- Almacenar referencias al XMLHttpRequest y no almacenarlas en ámbito global.
- Crear un único objeto XMLHttpRequest y reutilizarlo

El script en cuestión es el siguiente:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        sendRequest();
        function sendRequest(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo "updateTimeSeen.php?User=".$_SESSION['Email']."&pagina=Página_Principal"?>',
                success:
                function(data){
                    $('#time').html(data); //insert text of test.php into your div
                              
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                     // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
                    setInterval(sendRequest, 5000); // The interval set to 5 seconds
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

Pero no consigo aplicar estos conceptos a mi código. A ver si alguno me puede dar algún consejo o algo con lo que ir tirando.

Gracias.

Comment: porque no crear un SP(procedimiento almacenado) y hacer que se ejecute cada X tiempo.. si es como dices un usuario en concreto..!!

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo `setInterval` por `setTimeout`. Si usas  `setInterval` en respuesta a cada consulta estarás generando cada vez más temporizadores que harán a su vez nuevas peticiones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando `setInterval` en el callback de `complete`. `setInterval` dice "ejecuta esta función cada x milisegundos **de manera indefinida**", cada vez que el callback de `complete` se ejecuta vuelve a programar la ejecución de `sendRequest`, es por esto que la memoria está saliéndose de control, se crea 1 objeto de `setInterval` luego otro, estos 2 crean 2 más, 4, 8, 16... de manera exponencial.

Tienes un par de opciones, puedes reemplazar `setInterval` por `setTimeout` que ejecuta una sola vez la función que le pases:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    sendRequest();

    function sendRequest() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '...',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#time').html(data);
            },
            complete: function () {
                setTimeout(sendRequest, 5000);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

O puedes quitar el callback de `complete` y colocar el `setInterval` afuera de `sendRequest` así se llama cada 5 segundos.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function sendRequest() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '...',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#time').html(data);
            }
        });
    };

    setInterval(sendRequest, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Gracias!! En cuanto tenga un momento la pruebo, y si soluciona el problema la marcaré como correcta.

Comment: Resvisado. Al final he utilizado la primera opción y funciona a la perfección. Gracias!!